# moving files that contain part of a line from a file

Tags: bash, unix, xargs

I have a file that on each line is a string of some numbers such as

```
1234
2345
...
```

I need to move files that contain that number in their name followed by other stuff to a directory examples being

```
1234_hello_other_stuff_2334.pdf
2345_more_stuff_3343.pdf
```

I tried using xargs to do this, but my bash scripting isn't the best.  Can anyone share the proper command to accomplish what I want to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for i in `cat numbers.txt`; do
    mv ${i}_* examples
done
```

or (look ma, no `cat`!)

```
while read i; do
    mv ${i}_* examples
done < numbers.txt
```

Comment: I was going to use `sed`, but this is much more elegant.

Comment: Very nice, though you might want the `-b` flag, in case `mv` does some overwriting.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a for loop, but that could make for a really long command line.  If you have 20000 lines in numbers.txt, you might hit shell limits.  Instead, you could use a pipe:

```
cat numbers.txt | while read number; do
  mv ${number}_*.pdf /path/to/examples/
done
```

or:

```
sed 's/.*/mv -v &_*.pdf/' numbers.txt | sh
```

You can leave off the `| sh` for testing.  If there are other lines in the file and you only want to match lines with 4 digits, you could restrict your match:

```
sed -r '/^[0-9]{4}$/s//mv -v &_*.pdf/' numbers.txt | sh
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cat numbers.txt | xargs -n1 -I % find . -name '%*.pdf' -exec mv {} /path/to \;
```

`%` is your number (`-n1` means one at a time), and `'%*.pdf'` to `find` means it'll match all files whose names begin with that number; then it just copies to `/path/to` (`{}` is the actual file name).